# Can someone help me with real life application of the Multinomial Coefficient?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I have been studying the Multinomial Coefficient theorem for some time now. But I don't get how one can apply it in real life aside being used for making of selections and the number of times rearrangements of items can be made. I am very interested in the topic and I'll be happy if i can get more real life applications.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example is you use the multinomial when you want to find the number of ways to arrange the letters in a word like "MISSISSIPPI", in which you have one "M", four "I"s, four "S"s, and two "P"s. The number of distinct ways to arrange the letters is $\frac{11!}{1!4!4!2!}=\binom {11}{4,2,2}$. You also use it when you want to find $(x_1+x_2+...x_n)^k$.

Answer (score 0):

Typical real-life examples might arise in probability and statistics.  For example, you might find [this case study](http://cho.pol.illinois.edu/wendy/papers/casestudies.pdf) interesting.  While the details involving Bayesian analysis might be beyond you at this stage, the executive summary is: they analyze presidential election polls in 2008, using models that involve a multinomial distribution.  That is, if you take a random sample of $n$ voters
from a population with given probabilities of responses (say $p_1$ for candidate A, $p_2$ for candidate B, $p_3$ for candidate C, $p_4$ undecided), the probability of getting $n_1$ responses of A, $n_2$ of B, $n_3$ of C, $n_4$ undecided is $$ {n \choose n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4} p_1^{n_1} p_2^{n_2} p_3^{n_3} p_4^{n_4}$$
The statistician wants to estimate these probabilities, and how they changed over time.